# Read lat and long cordinates from a feature inside geojson file and set as center of the openlayers map on map load

Tags: openlayers

I am new to open layers and currently facing an issue reading and ploting lat and long to center of the map.

I have feature id inside geojson file which is `slat` and `slong` which I am able to read using `var SSlat= feature.get('sat')` and `var SSlong =feature.get('slong')` which I am calling inside a style function.

I get lat long for first execution, at the end of complete style function execution  var `SSlong` and var `SSLat` becomes undefined. please let me know is there any way around

```js
var SSlat;
var SSlong;

var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  SSlat=feature.get('slat');
  SSlong=feature.get('slong');
};

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc.geojson',
        crossOrigin:'null',
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        format: new GeoJSON(), 
      }),
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-9752120.04, 5132251.45],// here add lat and long which needs to be taken from geojson file
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would center the map on the feature's geometry when the feature is loaded.  If the slat and slong properties were different and preferred you could use them instead. You should assign your source to a variable to make it easier to reference.

```
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent.js';

let vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(), 
  });

vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(e) {
  map.getView().setCenter(getCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-9752120.04, 5132251.45],// here add lat and long which needs to be taken from geojson file
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

To center using `slat` and `slong` properties from features

```
vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(e) {
  var SSlat = e.feature.get('slat');
  var SSlong = e.feature.get('slong');
  if (SSlat && SSlong) {
    map.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([SSlong, SSlat]);
  }
});
```

you may need to use `[Number(SSlong), Number(SSlat)]` if the property is a string

Comment: Thanks mike, i have thousands of lat and long inside geojson file, in which slat and slog properties helps me center the map,so other lat and long ponts are visible. Please let me know how i can get them and set as center from above code, also where i need to place VectorSource.on('addfeature', function(e) {
  map.getView().setCenter(getCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
}); in my code

Comment: Do you mean just one of your thousands of features has `slat` and `slong` properties and you want to find and use that, or do the features have different values and you want to include all of the?

Comment: geometry has thousands of them, slat and slong properties have one value each.like "Slat": "1234.01477" " and Slong": "-1234.89216" which needs to be added to map center and this property are unique and appears only once in feature inside geojson file

Comment: You can only center on one point so you can't center on all of them.  To fit all your features in the view you can use `map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());`

Comment: i need to center at one point only not on all points, and that center point is stored in slat and slong. like Center: [-123.67,34.45]. where slat has -123.67 and slang has 34.5 please let me know

Comment: When a feature with those properties is added you can use them to center.

Comment: Thank you, i am getting refernce error: fromLatlong is undefined at map.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([SSlong,SSlat]));. can you please check. Also if i remove center:[-9752120.04, 5132251.45] map does not show up

Comment: `fromLonLat` will need to be imported if you are not already using it `import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj.js';`

Comment: Thanks got it working, but a small issue i am getting SSlat=-9752120.04612 and SSlong =5132251.45669. Now if is use   map.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([SSlong,SSlat])); map does not show. if i use   map.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([SSlat,SSlong,])); map loads but center is inccorect, showing some other continent. please let me know.

Comment: Also getting destination projection null. kindly check

Comment: You need to check your data.  If SSlong is outside +/- 180 or SSlat is outside +/- 90 they are not valid longitude or latitudes.

Comment: sorry my SSlong=-9752120.04612 and SSlat =5132251.45669 this and seems to be valid. it needs to be pointing to chicago in projection EPSG:3857. kindly let me know, also i have set the zoom to 13

Comment: If it's EPSG:3857 and so is your view you only need `map.getView().setCenter([SSlong, SSlat]);`  To set zoom 13 use `map.getView().setZoom(13);`

Comment: Hi Mike, facing an new issue with map disappearing. After above solution implemented,Map successfully loads with correct centering, once i mouse click and drag map a little, the entire map disappears. kindly let me know if there is any solution for this

Comment: If you open the console are there any errors logged?

Comment: No, I do not see any, i can see lat and log which is getting centered which i am dipalying using console.log. once map loads with center, then moment i right click and drag a lilltle, map disappears

Comment: on map load and centered, if i zoom in and zoom out using mouse first then right click and drag map wont disappear. If drag first then map disappears. Kindly help.

Comment: Sorry to bother, i had missed using [Number(SSlong), Number(SSlat)] my bad.Thank you mike for your time